# "France" pronunciation; /æ/ vs. /e/ in American accents

Tags: pronunciation, north-american-english, ae-raising

Native North American speakers! Please, help me understand one thing:

I thought I understood the difference between the /æ/ and /e/ sounds, but now I doubt that anyone can. Please listen to the US version of *France* in the Cambridge and Oxford online dictionaries:

1. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/france
2. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/france?q=france

What about the second? To me it sounds exactly like /e/ and nothing like /æ/. I searched for similar words like *fresh* and *french* and only confused even more.

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fresh_1?q=fresh

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/french_1?q=french

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/france?q=france

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fragile?q=fragile

Comment: In some American accents, /æ/ moves towards /ɛ/ before /n/. (And /ɛ/ moves towards /ɪ/, leading to the pronunciations of *pin* and *pen* being identical). In fact, this doesn't just happen before /n/, it's before all nasal consonants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that your second pronunciation from Oxford Learner's dictionary was hard to distinguish. It sounded like it may have been a more southern US dialect. See the [Pin-Pen merger](http://dialectblog.com/2011/04/17/pin-pen-merger/).

Wikipedia has a pretty good explanation and table showing [variations in accents of American English due to /æ/ tensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_short_A#.C3.A6_tensing). Depending on the consonant following /æ/, the sound may be raised, lengthened or diphthongized. In my central Canadian prairie accent, it's hard to distinguish a difference between *parish* and *perish*.

There are simpler word pairs to distinguish these sounds. Try [bat](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bat_1?q=bat) and [bet](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bet_1?q=bet).